# Decelerate UIScrollView in different direction than Paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that I want to page along the x axis but I want it to decelerate in the vertical direction. The Content size is taller than the frame size, so I'd like it to feel normal scrolling vertically, but still snap to the nearest page in the horizontal direction.

I'm manually implementing paging in the delegate methods, and it works well. I think the key is in `scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset` and specifically in the `targetContentOffset`. I'm just not sure on how to limit scrolling in the paging direction while allowing the `UIScrollView` to decelerate naturally in the other direction.